# Hive Error on lateral view explode(split(colA,','))A

Tags: split, hive, explode

I am getting the following error when I try and use explode lateral view and split together:

ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardListObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector

I have tried a few approaches, but can't figure out.
The datatype being split is an array that will use collect_set after to reorganize without duplicates

```
        select uid, e.cid, d.colD
        from tmp
            lateral view explode(split(colD,','))d as colD
            lateral view explode(cid)e as cid
```

Any help is welcomed! Thanks in advance Friends!

Comment: You're having two aliases for the lateral views. Remove one of them in each line.

Comment: What colD and cid initially contain and what their data type in table definition?

Comment: Thank you for responses. Tried the alias reduction, but no dice. Both are array<string> datatypes

Comment: Figured it out...a little ugly, but just added an interim temp table to explode out from the array struct as I guess the split won't work on sets/lists. Guess could've written another layer of subquery too...Oh well, sledgehammer strikes again. hahaha. Thank you both for your effort to help